# Easyui form submit to webapi didn't get response result

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, jquery-easyui

```
function saveUser() {
        $('#fm').form('submit', {
            url: url,
            onSubmit: function () {
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#dlg').dialog('close');        
                $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    
            }
        });
    }
```

I post to asp.net webapi at the backend, and i have tried to return "application/json","text/plain","text/html" Content-type, but when it goes to success function, there is always no data return. And when i open Chrome dev tools, i can see the response is right there.
[image]
[image]

In WebApi:

```
ajaxResult.Result = new { result = "ok" };

return new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ajaxResult.Result), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain") };
```

Comment: do a alert(data) in your success function

Comment: @madalinivascu i tried, and it alert empty.